# Change datetime format of x-axis?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I have a `TChart` with an area series. The area Points are mapped to datetime values. How can I change the format of the date labels on the x-axis?

This does not work:

```
area.add(new DateTime(timestamp), value); // Date value!
...
chart.getAxes().getBottom().getLabels().setDateTimeFormat("MMM 'yy");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives me an IllegalArgumentException:

```
new DateTime(2012,1,1).toString("MMM 'yy");
```

The comma **'** in the string format argument is unnaccepted.

As you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the single quote is used to avoid interpretation. Put two single quotes to draw a single quote:

```
new DateTime(2012,1,1).toString("MMM ''yy");
```

Comment: That's correct. Is it the underlying API that is causing the problem or can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need set the XValues of Area as DateTime as do in next line of code:

```
area.getXvalues().setDateTime(true);
```

Please, try again if adding my line of code help you to solve your problem.

I hope will helps.

Thanks,